# how to fill with page with json.data with better looking code?

Tags: json, push

until now, this is kind of how i fill my page with data i received from $.getJSON.

```
collection.push("div class='item'><img src='" + items[i].imgurl + "' /><h1>" + items[i].itemname + "</h1><p id='desription" + i + "'>" + items[i].infotxt + "</p></div>);
```

those lines look so terrible inside my editor, that i wonder if this is even the right way to do it...

might there something like a class costructor for this or anything like that?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the jquery-json plugin?

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/